# Access global data in iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, database

I'm creating a website with an according app for iOS/Android and I'm doing some research for how I should do everything. I need to be able to post data from the different platforms and I want to access the same data from every platform, kind of like a wall where ypu can write stuff. I'm thinking that the data needs to be stored in a database but how do I access i.e. an SQL database from iOS/Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple research would've brought you a great [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) on how to link a MySQL database through PHP to an Android app.
You'll be required the basics of PHP though so you may want to study a bit about that prior to starting.

Comment: Android isn't my biggest problem, I would need the same for iOS then

Comment: The concept is the same, you create a database in MySQL and you connect it through PHP, all of the first part is multi-platform, on how to do the second part in iOS you need to research a bit further, I don't believe it's hard, try to translate it step by step.

Comment: Sounds fair, I might try that. I have some experience with PHP so it shouldn't be too hard :)

Comment: Next time research a bit ! ; ) If you have any other questions just ask ahead in a different question and close this one as this one is also really general.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [parse.com](https://parse.com). This likely provides what you need without having to set up server with a database, etc. You can access your data on parse.com from iOS, Android, your web site, and a number of other platforms should you need to.